# Is it possible to create app and modules in odoo 10 community Edition

Tags: python, odoo, erp

I need help and I am new to Odoo Erp. I have question that custom modules can be build in community edition Odoo 10 and new apps also.

If its not possible by default then can we buy and install those apps in community edition.

Please provide help links for building apps and modules in community edition.

Your help will really be appreciated
Regards,
Jawad

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can develop your module even follow this official tutorial of [odoo.com](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html) or in
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1HWQqxgqHY) for example

to download or buy a module you can also find in [odoo apps](https://www.odoo.com/apps)